# pullback map on k-tensors of a linear isomorphism and finding it's inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, tensors

This question was asked in an assignment on k-tensor forms and I am having hard time solving this problem. I have been following my class notes which are based on the book of john lee.

Question: Let V, W be two vector spaces of dimension n. Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear isomorphism and $T^{*} : L^{k} (V) \to L^{k} (W)$ be the corresponding pullback map on k-tensors. Show that $T^{*}$ is a linear isomorphism and find it's inverse.

Definition of  pullback tensor : Suppose that $L : V\to  W$ is a linear transformation, and that $\alpha \in T^k(W^{*})$. We then define the pullback tensor $L^{*} \alpha$ by
$(L^{*}(\alpha))(v_1,...,v_k) = \alpha(L(v_1),L(v_2),...,L(v_k))$.

I have read the relevant theory but I am not sure how it can be used to solve the problems. Can you please give hints for this. I don't have much to show as attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Concisely，$T^k(-^*)$ is a contravaraint functor. Therefore, it takes isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

More specifically, for $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to W$, you should verify that $(g\circ f)^*=f^*\circ g^*$; for $id_V:V\to V$, $id_V^*=id_{T^k(V^*)}$. By these properties, if $f:U\to V$ is an isomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}:V\to U$, then $(f\circ f^{-1})^*=(f^{-1})^*\circ f^*=id$. Similarly, $(f)^*\circ (f^{-1})^*=id$. It follows that $f^*$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Z.HHe But how to define it's inverse?

Comment: @Avenger In your notations, $(L^{-1})^{*}$ is defined by $((L^{-1})^{*}(\alpha))(v_1,...,v_k) = \alpha(L^{-1}(v_1),L^{-1}(v_2),...,L^{-1}(v_k))$. Then $(L^{-1})^{*}$ is the inverse of $L^{*}$. (verify it!)